# Using previous result inside Module

Tags: scoping

I enjoy using "%" to capture the previous output as it allows me to split big tasks into chunks without having to introduce lots of intermediate variable names. Consider an overly simple example:

```
x = 2;
x + 4;
%^2;
y = % - 3;
{x, y}
(*{2, 33}*)
```

How can I accomplish a similar thing inside Module. I naively tried

```
f[x_] := Module[{y},
  x + 4;
  %^2;
  y = % - 3;
  {x, y}
  ]
f[2]
(*{2, -3 + Null}*)
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't think `%` can work inside a `Module`, but if you don't want unnecessary variables, can't you do something like`y = x + 4; y = y^2; y = y - 3`?

Comment: `f[x_] := Module[{y}, x + 4 // #^2 & // (y = # - 3) &; {x, y}]`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I could do, put it upsets my sensibilities using a variable for intermediate steps when the results of the intermediate steps are not what that variable is supposed to represent. Perhaps I'm being a tad particular though!

Comment: @Karsten7. hmm yeah maybe that could do it. Although in reality each line is quite long so I need to have an individual line for each step, and splitting up your suggestion into individual lines looks a bit messy from the way Mathematica formats it.

Comment: Starting each line with `//` might look better (but still strange). It's also more typing and one should not forget the extra `()` in things like `(y = # - 3) &`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a problem peculiar to `Module`; `%` won't work in the way you expect in any function definition because it always refers to the last top-level output. Consider, the much simpler

```
g[x_] := (x^2; % + 1)

42
```

> `42`

```
g[5]
```

> `43`

```
g[5]
```

> `44`

You see that `g` ignores the previous evaluation of `x^2` and returns the last top-level output increased by 1.

My recommendation for those times when you want to compute a complicated expression in steps is to use a single local variable repeatedly. Thus, I would rewrite `f` as

```
f[x_] :=
  Module[{y},
    y = x + 4;
    y = y^2;
    y = y - 3;
    {x, y}]
```

To check that this gives same result as writing the computation as a single expression, I write

```
h[x_] := {x, (x + 4)^2 - 3}
```

Then

```
f[x] == h[x]
```

gives

`True`